# Use equation $\sin \frac{\pi }{{2n}} + \cos \frac{\pi }{{2n}} = \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2}$ to find the range of integer n

Tags: trigonometry

Let n  be a positive integer such that $\sin \frac{\pi }{{2n}} + \cos \frac{\pi }{{2n}} = \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2}$, then

(A) $6 \le n \le8$

(B) $4 < n \le8$

(C) $4 \le n \le8$

(D) $4 < n <8$

My approach is as follow

$\sin \frac{\pi }{{2n}} + \cos \frac{\pi }{{2n}} = \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\sin \frac{\pi }{{2n}} + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\cos \frac{\pi }{{2n}} = \frac{{\sqrt n }}{{2\sqrt 2 }}$

$ \Rightarrow \sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{{2n}} + \frac{\pi }{4}} \right) = \frac{{\sqrt n }}{{2\sqrt 2 }} = t$

$\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} \le t \le 1$

$\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} \le \frac{{\sqrt n }}{{2\sqrt 2 }} \le 1 \Rightarrow 2 \le \sqrt n  \le 2\sqrt 2  \Rightarrow 4 \le n \le 8$ but official answer is (D). Where I am making mistake

Comment: The difference between your answer and (D) is whether $n = 4$ and $n=8$ are solutions, which is trivial to check. That said, D implies B and C are correct, so there is some ambiguity in the question (unless it is stated that one should choose the *best* answer)

Comment: question is correct it is from IIT JEE 1994 test paper

Comment: I think your mistake is assuming $2^{-1/2} \le t \le 1$. The relationship between $n$ (or $t$) is more complex because it is in the argument for $\sin$. It is clear that $n = 4, 8$ do not work (simply by plugging in)

Comment: I think a better way of putting Gregory's point is that you stopped too soon. As soon as you got an inequality you didn't bother to see if it could be refined, but decided that was your final answer. $4, 8$ are easily eliminated. My question is why (A) is not the official answer, though, since (A) means $n$ is one of $6, 7, 8$ while (D) means $n$ is one of $5, 6, 7$. Since $6$ is only integer that does work, I see no reason to prefer (D) over (A).